# $X_1,...,X_{2n}$ i.i.d. standard Normal, find limiting distribution of $Z_n = U_n/V_n$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

$X_1,...,X_{2n}$ i.i.d. standard Normal, find limiting distribution of $Z_n = U_n/V_n$
where $U_n = X_1/X_2 + X_3/X_4+ \dots + X_{2n-1}/X_{2n}$

$V_n = X_1^2+ \dots + X_n^2$

Attempt:

It can be shown that each $X_i/X_{i+1}$ follows a standard cauchy distribution. Further, it can easily be shown that $$(X_1^2+...+X_n^2)/n$$ converges in probability to 1.

Thus define we can find the solution by finding what $U_n/n$ converges to in distribution using Slutsky's theorem. Ths is where i am stuck. the solution that is provided is a standard cauchy distribution. By the provided answer I see that $U_n$/n must somehow converge in distribution to a standard cauchy distribution, but i don't see how this is.

Comment: Check the characteristic function of Cauchy distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Characteristic_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(\xi_i)_{i\in \Bbb N}$ i.i.d. with $\xi_1 \sim \text{Cauchy}(0,1)$. Then the characteristic function of $\xi_1$ is given by
$$\varphi_{\xi_1} (t) = e^{-\vert t \vert}$$
and
$$\varphi_{\frac{\xi_1}{n}} (t) = \Bbb E [e^{i\frac{\xi_1}{n} t}] = \varphi_{\xi_1} (\frac t n) = e^{-\frac 1 n\vert t \vert}$$
The characteristic function of $S_n := \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n \xi_i$ is due to the independence
$$\varphi_{S_n} (t) = \varphi_{\frac{\xi_1}{n}} (t) \cdot \ldots \cdot \varphi_{\frac{\xi_n}{n}} (t) = e^{-\frac 1 n\vert t \vert} \cdot \ldots \cdot e^{-\frac 1 n\vert t \vert} = e^{-\vert t \vert}$$
This shows (since the characteristic function is uniwue) that $S_n \sim  \text{Cauchy}(0,1)$. Trivially it follows that
$$S_n \to  \text{Cauchy}(0,1)$$
in distribution.

Comment: Thank you for this, I will look into the characteristic function. I wanted to do something similar for moment generating, but could not since it does not exist.